# Looping in JSX produces a single child element containing an array. I want multiple children

Tags: reactjs, iteration, jsx, children

I have a component called `<Accordian>`.  using it looks like this

```
<Accordian>
    <AccordianSection label=“section1”>
        <div> some content <div>
    </AccordianSection>
    <AccordianSection label=“section2”>
        <div> some other <div>
    </AccordianSection>
</Accordian>
```

It works great. I run into problems when I create sections using a JSX map iteration:

```
<Accordian>
    <AccordianSection label=“section1”>
        <div> some content <div>
    </AccordianSection>

    { props.sections.map( section => 
        <AccordianSection label=“section.label”>
            <div> section.contents <div>
        </AccordianSection>
    )}
    <AccordianSection label=“section2”>
        <div> some other <div>
    </AccordianSection>
</Accordian>
```

The problem is that the Accordion code expects its children to be a list of `AccordianSection`s.  But the children of the above `Accordian` look like `[AccordianSection, Array<AccordianSection>, AccordianSection]`.  I basically want to "spread" the elements produced by the map so that the children of `Accordian` is a flat list of `AccordianSections`.   Any ideas?

Comment: Do `props.sections.flat().map.(...)`. More info on [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, however you could change the logic in `Accordion` by using `Array.prototype.flat` on the `children` array. It will flatten the array:

```js
const children = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5];
console.log(children.flat());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const renderAccordianSection = () => {
  return [
    <AccordianSection key="section1" label=“section1”>
        <div> some content <div>
    </AccordianSection>,
    ...props.sections.map(section => 
        <AccordianSection key="section.label" label=“section.label”>
            <div> section.contents <div>
        </AccordianSection>
    ),
    <AccordianSection key="section2" label=“section2”>
        <div> some other <div>
    </AccordianSection>
  ]
}

<Accordian>
  {renderAccordianSection ()}
</Accordian>
```